# TFS Test Results Detailed Reports not keeping with the SoapUI Project Structure

Tags: testing, junit, tfs, soapui, ready-api

I am currently triggering my SoapUI test suites from TFS command line, which it working correctly and I am able to trigger the build and view the results.

My issue is that I have 3 test suites each with up to 16 test cases. When I view the detailed report in TFS, the test cases are not structured in Test Suite format, they are all bundled into one category. Even when I changed the Group by to Test Suite.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, the TCs have the same name and it would be great if I were able to set it so that I can view these results in the same structure as the SoapUI Project:

```
-Project
    -Test Suite 01
        -Test Case 01
        -Test Case 02
        -Test Case N...
    -Test Suite 02
        -Test Case 01
        -Test Case 02
        -Test Case N...
    -Test Suite 03
        -Test Case 01
        -Test Case 02
        -Test Case N...
```

Comment: I can see 36/39 passed, is it the same case for the failed ones ? With TFS I end up having detail only on failed steps ... there may be an option to select

Comment: So there are 3 Test Suites. TS1 has 11 TCs, TS2 has 14, and TS3 has 14. 2 TCs failed in TS1 and 1 TC failed TS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will only group the test suites managed by [Test Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-testmanager-web) extension, take a look at this thread [Create a test plan and test suite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/test/create-a-test-plan?view=vsts).

You could generate your own test report with the your Project Structure, and then use  [Publish Test Results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=vsts) to publish test results to TFS server.

> The task supports popular test result formats including JUnit, NUnit
>   2, NUnit 3, Visual Studio Test (TRX), and xUnit 2. If you use the
>   built-in tasks such as Visual Studio Test to run tests, results are
>   automatically published and you do not need a separate publish test
>   results task.